# Azure App Service multi-container docker compose app not starting some containers

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, caddy

I have the following docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container for supported attributes

services:
  temp-db:
    # clone of postgres:13-alpine because app service allows one registry only
    image: mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=temp-qa-only-password
      - POSTGRES_USER=qa-app
      - POSTGRES_DB=cashflow_db
    restart: always

  temp-cache:
    # clone of redis:6.2-alpine since app service only allows one image registry
    image: mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/redis
    command: [ "redis-server", "--requirepass", "temp-qa-only-password" ]

  api-server:
    image: mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/backend:qa
    entrypoint: /apiserver
    restart: always

  frontend:
    image: mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/frontend:qa
    ports:
      # default port used by azure app service and in the caddyfile
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      API_SERVER_ADDRESS: "api-server:80"
      API_MOCK_SERVER_ADDRESS: "api-mock-server:80"

  api-mock-server:
    image: mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/mock:qa
    restart: always
```

that deploys to azure app service successfully. The frontend container is a caddy reverse proxy that has the following caddy file:

```
:8080  {
    log {
        output stdout
        format console
    }

    encode zstd gzip

    handle /api/* {  
        reverse_proxy {$API_SERVER_ADDRESS}
    }

    handle /api-mock/* {  
        reverse_proxy {$API_MOCK_SERVER_ADDRESS}
    }

    handle {
        root * /srv
        try_files {path} /index.html
        file_server
    }
}
```

After deployment, I can reach any `/api-mock/` path of the app but none of the paths to the actual backend with the uri `/api/healthz` for example work. All of them return a 502 error code. I also see caddy logs below in the app service portal:

```
"level":"error","ts":1693338653.1622438,"logger":"http.log.error.log0","msg":"dial tcp: lookup api-server on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host","request":{"remote_ip":"172.16.41.1","remote_port":"16691","proto":"HTTP/1.1","method":"GET","host":"foobar-mvp-app-service.azurewebsites.net","uri":"/api/v1/healthz", ...
```

I have also seen these logs in the ap service's Deployment Center:

```
docker run -d --name foobar-mvp-app-service_api-server_18_371c77b2 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=foobar-mvp-app-service -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=foobar-mvp-app-service.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=800304fbf39ff602bd61f284c09df29350e156b11faf5c746bca30008656bbc9 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/backend:qa apiserver
```

but no logs after from the api server. It appears as though the container never actually started but there are no error logs or logs that say "Stopped" that are seen when a container exits.

- Tried to specify hostname
- changing ports on the API server
- api server waits for the db to come up
- api server logs to stdout and logs are observed when running the same image on an ubuntu machine by copying the `docker run` command seen in the app service deployment logs.

Answer (score 0):

> "dial tcp: lookup api-server on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"

Check the DNS servers that are configured for the Docker container
**`docker inspect --format='{{ .HostConfig.Dns }}' <docker-container-id>`**

After running the command, it should be a list of DNS servers. If the list is empty, or if the list does not contain the correct DNS servers for your environment, you will need to configure the DNS servers for the Docker container.

Use this command **`curl <load-balancer-ip>/api/healthz`** Docker container is able to connect to the Azure App Service load balancer.

I tried by crested a simple docker-compose file as you can check below.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  backend:
    image: mvpdockerregistry.azurecr.io/backend:qa
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=temp-db
      - DB_PORT=5432
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    restart: always

  temp-db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=temp-qa-only-password
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    restart: always
```

I Configured similar to your Azure App Service setup multiple services, their images, environment variables, and any dependencies.

- If your containers need to communicate with each other, test this communication locally. For example, if your backend container connects to a database container, ensure that the connection works as expected.

As you check that I included logging to generate logs in Json format file to know the issue exactly.

- Run the **API server** container on an Ubuntu machine using the same Docker run command you observed in the Azure App Service Deployment Center. Monitor the logs to see if it starts successfully and connects to the required services.

Comment: * I tried the local testing and the healthz api returned 200 locally but just not in when deployed in app service
* azure app service doesn't allow running docker commands directly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app is the tutorial I am following.

Comment: it's important to ensure that your containers and services are configured correctly for this platform. Azure App Service uses a container network, and there could be network-related issues affecting communication between containers. please check in detail.